# Jquery Selectors based on the Value of Three Drop Down Menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I am working on with three drop-down menus each of which have three options. Together these three drop-down menus create a system that can be in any one of twenty seven states. For each drop-down, there is option 1, option 2, and all (which is the union of option 1 and 2).

Depending on what state these three drop-down menus are in, I want to display or hide different divs.  These divs have classes of this form `class="distribution-(select-1)-(select-2)-(select-3)"`

I am trying to find a DRY way of coding this up without relying on 27 different conditionals.

Here are the drop-down menus:

```
<div  style = "margin-top:1cm; font-size:125%">
    <strong>Clickout Type&nbsp;</strong>
    <select class = "clickouts" >
        <option value = "all" selected="selected">All</option>
        <option value = "clickouts" >Clickouts</option>
        <option value = "preferred" >Preferred Clickouts</option>
    </select>
    <strong>Graph Type&nbsp;</strong>
    <select class = "graph-type" >
        <option value = "all" selected="selected">All</option>
        <option value = "hist" >Histograms</option>
        <option value = "percent" >Percent</option>
    </select>
    <strong>Roll-up Type&nbsp;</strong>
    <select class = "roll-up" >
        <option value = "all" selected="selected">All</option>
        <option value = "aggregate" >Aggregate</option>
        <option value = "granular" >Granular</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Here are some examples of the div classes:
`distribution-hist-clickouts-aggregate, distribution-percent-clickouts-aggregate, class="distribution-hist-clickouts-granular", distribution-percent-clickouts-granular`

Here is the jquery for the first seven states:

```
$('.clickouts, .graph-type, .roll-up').change(function(){
    var graph_type = $('.graph-type').val(); 
    var roll_up = $('.roll-up').val();
    var clickouts = $('.clickouts').val(); 

    if (graph_type == 'all' & roll_up == 'all' & clickouts == 'all'){
        $('div[class*="distribution"]').css('display', 'block');
    }
    if (graph_type == 'all' & roll_up == 'all' & clickouts == 'clickouts'){
        $('div[class*="clickout"]').css('display', 'block');
        $('div[class*="preferred"]').css('display', 'none');
    }

    else if (graph_type == 'all' & roll_up == 'all' & clickouts == 'preferred'){
        $('div[class*="clickout"]').css('display', 'none');
        $('div[class*="preferred"]').css('display', 'block');
    }

    else if (graph_type == 'hist' & roll_up == 'all' & clickouts == 'all'){
        $('div[class*="hist"]').css('display', 'block');
        $('div[class*="percent"]').css('display', 'none');
    }

    else if (graph_type == 'percent' & roll_up == 'all' & clickouts == 'all'){
        $('div[class*="hist"]').css('display', 'none');
        $('div[class*="percent"]').css('display', 'block');
    }

    else if (graph_type == 'all' & roll_up == 'aggregate' & clickouts == 'all'){
        $('div[class*="aggregate"]').css('display', 'block');
        $('div[class*="granular"]').css('display', 'none');
    }

    else if (graph_type == 'all' & roll_up == 'granular' & clickouts == 'all'){
        $('div[class*="aggregate"]').css('display', 'none');
        $('div[class*="granular"]').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

Comment: eh... my method has already been suggested... oh well: http://jsfiddle.net/bFts9/

Comment: I think [my approach](http://jsbin.com/ohinog/2/edit#javascript,html,live) is the simplest of all the ones suggested so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will change your complex class `class="distribution-(select-1)-(select-2)-(select-3)` to set of classes `class="distribution (select-1) (select-2) (select-3)` you can use the following script:

```
$('.clickouts, .graph-type, .roll-up').change(function(){
    var graph_type = $('.graph-type').val(); 
    var roll_up = $('.roll-up').val();
    var clickouts = $('.clickouts').val(); 

    graph_type = (graph_type == "all" ? "" : "." + graph_type);
    roll_up = (roll_up == "all" ? "" : "." + roll_up);
    clickouts = (clickouts == "all" ? "" : "." + clickouts);

    var selector = '#container div' + graph_type + roll_up + clickouts;

    $('#container div:visible').hide();
    $(selector).show();
});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/9R5zj/9/

Comment: was about to suggest the same thing

Comment: How would this account however for the all conditions, which is the union of either option.

Comment: oh, yes... forgot to mention. You have 2 options: set for 'all' empty values and use script as I used, otherwise you can change the script about to compare with 'all' value, like this: `graph_type = (graph_type == "all" ? "" : "." + graph_type);`

Comment: I've updated the sample and jsfiddle to fit your initial requirements with 'all' value for `All`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there are several things that will help to refactor this.

An easy thing that you should remember is that elements can have more than one class. That means, instead of having a div with the `distribution-hist-clickouts-aggregate` class, you can give the div four classes, like this:

```
<div class="distribution hist clickouts aggregate"></div>
```

Also, instead of having the `value` of the select options as `all`, you make it easier for your program to understand by putting the selectors in the values:

```
<option value = ".aggregate, .granular" selected="selected">All</option>    
<option value = ".aggregate" >Aggregate</option>    
<option value = ".granular" >Granular</option>
```

I'm not sure I completely understand the logic behind all of the `if` statements, but you can do something to this effect:

```
$("div.distribution").hide();
$(graph_type).show();
$(roll_up).show();
$(clickouts).show();
```

You can see what I'm suggesting in action on [this demo](http://jsbin.com/ohinog/2/edit#javascript,html,live).